# jQuery toggle resetting immediately after complete

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

I have some elements I want to automatically hide (display: none) when the page is small, and automatically show (display: block) when the page is large.  I have this working with bootstrap4, and it looks like this:

```
<section id="categories">
    <p data-toggle="categories-list">Categories</p>
    <ul id="categories-list" class="d-none d-lg-block">

    </ul>
</section>
```

However, I'd also like users to be able to reopen the list when it's hidden, or hide it when it's shown.  I'm trying to add toggle ability with the following code:

```
$('[data-toggle]').each(function () {
    $(this)[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var target = $(this)[0].dataset.toggle;
        $('#' + target).toggle('slow');
    }); 
});
```

This almost works.  If I click when the ul is hidden (small page), it slowly expands to be visible, but then it immediately disappears again.  Or if it's already visible (on a large page), it will slowly disappear, but then immediately reappear as soon as the animation is done.

Are the boostrap styles enforcing those display rules despite the changes I'm trying to make, even though the page size isn't changing?

(I'm fairly new to front end development in general, and bootstrap in particular.)

Edit: I know bootstrap has some sort of "collapse" functionality.  Should I be trying to use that instead?  Maybe it would play nicer instead of trying to do jquery.

Edit2: Looking over collapse more, I see they use 'data-toggle', which is exactly what I called mine.  Could that be part of the problem?

Edit3: I tried removing my javascript code completely, and instead using data-toggle and data-target as in the bootstrap4 documentation.  I get exactly the same functionality as what my javascript code was doing.

Update after JasonB's proposed solution:

New html:

```
<section id="categories">
    <p data-toggle="#categories-list">Categories</p>
    <ul id="categories-list" class="custom-none custom-lg-block">
    </ul>
</section>
```

New css:

```
.custom-none {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .custom-lg-block {
        display: block;
    }   
}
```

New javascript:

```
$('[data-toggle]').each(function () {
    $(this)[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var target = $(this)[0].dataset.toggle;
        if ($(target).css('display') == 'none') {
            $(target).css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $(target).css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

This is so very close to working.  The page loads correctly, with menus display:none on a small page, and display:block on a large page.  I can resize the browser window, and the menus expand or collapse as desired, once the 992px target is hit.  And I can click on the menus to toggle them, and it works as expected.

The only remaining problem is once I click on the menus, and manually set their .css('display'), that value becomes locked in.  Resizing the page no longer causes them to collapse or expand.  This isn't entirely a deal breaker, as the main purpose of this is to handle mobile (where they won't suddenly make the page bigger), but it could look weird on desktop if they shrink the window down while having all the menus expanded.

Update:

Added this javascript and removed the @media min-width, and it's working:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('[data-toggle]').each(function () {
            var target = $(this)[0].dataset.toggle;
            $(target).css('display', 'none');
        });
    } else {
        $('[data-toggle]').each(function () {
            var target = $(this)[0].dataset.toggle;
            $(target).css('display', 'block');
        });
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: $(target).css('display', ''); // will set it to inherited

Comment: That's not really what I want, though.  I do want to change the display value.  But I want it to change again if the page resizes.

It feels like I need some sort of javascript to detect width changes, instead of relying on @media min-width.  Because I don't think CSS alone can really respond to this.  In effect, I want the display value to be whatever was last (toggled based off a click, or changed based off a screen resize, whichever happened last.)

Comment: Just added javascript that checks if the width has changed and then updates the display values.  That seems to work.  Not sure this is the best way, especially regarding performance.  Will update question with details.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('[data-toggle]').each(function() {
  $(this)[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var target = $(this)[0].dataset.toggle;
    $('#' + target).toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.dave-d-none {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .dave-d-lg-block {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="categories">
  <p data-toggle="categories-list">Categories</p>
  <ul id="categories-list" class="dave-d-none dave-d-lg-block">
    <li>This is the hidden stuff.</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

I beleve Bootstrap's d-none class is the issue.

`.d-none` adds `display:none !important;` and it's that !important flag that is getting in the way. If you use your own class or an inline style that is just `display:none;` you should be able to get the desired effect.

Comment: Oh good call.  I hadn't thought about "!important".  I don't think it's as simple as getting rid of .d-none, though, because I think d-lg-block is also maybe "!important", so it'll hold it visible when the page is large.  So I can't make the problem go away entirely without getting rid of the bootstrap classes altogether, and I need them.  Can I maybe make my own toggle function that does something like .css('display', 'block !important')?

Comment: I tried using .css('display', 'block ! important').  It doesn't work.  Reading .css('display') immediately after still shows 'none'.

Comment: I added a snippet to show that you can get the desired show/hide behavior based on screen width by no using `!important` at all. The trouble there is that your toggle javascript takes precedence once it has been triggered so that logic needs to be handled a bit differently.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a try in the morning. I assume I'll have to do something similar for d-lg-block as well, right? Or is that not marked as important?

Comment: You are correct; !important is in that one too. The css is `.d-lg-block { display:block!important; } with a media query for the lg breakpoint.

Comment: I added an update at the end of my post.  It's very close to working now, except now once I click on the menus, and manually set their .css('display'), that value becomes locked in. Resizing the page no longer causes them to collapse or expand.

Does setting a style value directly automatically override class values?  If so, maybe instead of setting them directly, I need to just be modifying class values and not setting display directly.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem, as JasonB pointed out, was that the bootstrap css was adding !important, which was overriding any changes I tried to programmatically make.

I tried to make my own CSS that didn't use !important, but then when I was setting display:none/block manually, it would always override the CSS class, even when the window width changed.

The solution I came up with was to use javascript to detect window width changes, instead of relying on the CSS.  CSS still sets the initial display state, but after that, all changes are made by javascript.  I doubt this is the best solution, but it's all I've been able to make work so far.  Below is the HTML, CSS, and Javascript that works:

```
$('[data-toggle]').each(function () {
    $(this)[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var target = $(this)[0].dataset.toggle;
        if ($(target).css('display') == 'none') {
            $(target).css('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $(target).css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 992) {
        $('[data-toggle]').each(function () {
            var target = $(this)[0].dataset.toggle;
            $(target).css('display', 'none');
        });
    } else {
        $('[data-toggle]').each(function () {
            var target = $(this)[0].dataset.toggle;
            $(target).css('display', 'block');
        });
    }
}, true);
```

---

```
.custom-none {
    display: none;
}

.custom-lg-block {
    display: block;
}
```

---

```
<section id="categories">
    <p data-toggle="#categories-list">Categories</p>
    <ul id="categories-list" class="custom-none custom-lg-block">
    </ul>
</section>
```